# Data from displayed summary must submit to database using modal form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Sorry, english is not my Native Language. I've been really stuck since I've just use PHP to store data in my Database (I'm using mysql).

So in my html I have the main

```js
   function display() {
 var canvas = document.getElementById('displaycanvas');
 context = canvas.getContext('2d');
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    if(document.getElementById('color1').checked){ context.strokeStyle="#FF0000"; } else if(document.getElementById('color2').checked){ context.strokeStyle="#0000FF"; }
    if (document.getElementById('shape1').checked) {
           context.beginPath(); context.arc(95,50,40,0,2*Math.PI); context.stroke(); }

    if (document.getElementById('shape2').checked) {
            context.beginPath(); context.rect(50, 27, 50, 100); context.stroke(); }
   }

$('#review').click(function () {
       $('#shape').html($('input[name="shape_design"]:checked').val());
       $('#color').html($('input[name="color_design"]:checked').val());
});
```

```html
 

   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="displaycanvas"></canvas>
    <form role="form" id="showchoices" name="showchoices" method="post" onsubmit="return entry_check()" action="/user/ps/add/">
           <div> <input type="radio" id="shape1" name="shape_design"   value="CIRCLE" onchange="display()" /> O 
            <input type="radio" id="shape2" name="shape_design"  value="RECTANGLE" onchange="display()" /> [] </div>

          <div>  <input type="radio" id="color1" name="color_design"  value="RED"  onchange="display()"/> RED  
            <input type="radio" id="color2" name="color_design"  value="BLUE" onchange="display()" /> BLUE </div>  </form> 
   
    <input type="button" name="btn" value="Review" id="review" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#con_rev" class="btn btn-primary" />

    <!-- this modal displays the SUMMARY,working fine -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="con_rev" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">Confirm Order</div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  
                 <form action="#myModal1" role="form" method="POST"> <!-- display for the Order sent -->
                    <p> Shape: <span id="shape" name="shape" ></span> </p>
                    <p> Color: <span id="color" name="color" ></span> </p>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="order"/>  </div>
            </div> </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Everything above is working fine, I just would like to show how it looks like.

So this is how it works. Once the user will choose her/his choices, first it will display a modal that "Summarizes" the data its modal id="con_rev".
So here we have the data displayed based on user's choices.
Now I've made another modal when the user decides to "ORDER" or submit its choices.

Modal same in HTML page: (this one isn't working)

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal modal-child" data-backdrop-limit="1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-modal-parent="#myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">ORDER SENT</h4> </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
            <?php
            include 'database.php';
            $pdo = Database::connect();

            $shape = $_POST['shape'];
            $color = $_POST['color'];

    $dbc = @mysql_connect('localhost' , 'root', '');
    @mysql_select_db('order_db', $dbc);

    $query = "INSERT INTO choice VALUES(NULL, '$shape','$color')";

    if(@mysql_query($query,$dbc)){
        print '<h1> Your order has been sent </h1>';    }  
        else{ print '<p> failed. '.mysql_error().'</p>'; }
            ?>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I've followed different sources of tutorial and combined them. 
It won't display error, but if I'm going to check at my database its still empty. Hope you could really help me out.
In case you'll use Ajax, our class haven't tackled it so I'm not sure if I could advance but still if its the only way I'll take it!
 Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  `mysql_connect()` is deprecated and has been removed in PHP 7.0.0

Now what is confusing me is that, you're taking the pdo instance (pressumably it's *PDO* extension) through:

```
include 'database.php';
$pdo = Database::connect();
```

but didn't use it at all:

Try this (I've adapted to your configuration by using PDO extension) :

```
<div id="myModal1" class="modal modal-child" data-backdrop-limit="1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-modal-parent="#myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title">ORDER SENT</h4> </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

<?php
$host = 'localhost';
$user = 'root';
$pass = '';
$database = 'order_db';

$shape = $_POST['shape'];
$color = $_POST['color'];

$options = array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false
);

 try {
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=host;dbname=database", $user, $pass, $options);
}

catch (PDOException $e) {
      echo "connection error : <br> :";
      echo $e->getMessage();
    }    

    $sql = "INSERT INTO 'choice'  VALUES (:mynull, :shape, :color)";
    $statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);

     $statement->bindValue(':mynull', null, PDO::PARAM_INT);
     $statement->bindValue(':shape', $shape, PDO::PARAM_STR);
     $statement->bindValue(':color', $color, PDO::PARAM_STR);   
     $inserted = $statement->execute();

     if($inserted){
     echo 'Your order has been sent !<br>';
    }

?>

 </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

also don't use `@` , it's intended to suppress the errors thus you cann't see it when the error thrown.

Comment: thank you! I'll try this out. At my very top in my html I have this code . `<?php
  $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
  if (!$link) { die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error()); }
  if (!mysql_select_db('myrnas')) { die('Could not select database: ' . mysql_error());}
?>`

Comment: aww, my entire page isn't working now, using xampp as my localhost.

Comment: It should have been working, it might be just you that have no idea what you're doing :P Hehe

Comment: It might be, since some codes were not familiar to me. Is the "`(':mynull', null, PDO::PARAM_INT)`" here supposed for order_ID?
I have an Order_ID in my database which I've autoincremented.

Comment: No bro, I did that which is supposed to pass `null` as I saw you did `"INSERT INTO choice VALUES(NULL, '$shape','$color')"`, I didn't even know if that *order_ID* would be autoincrementing field. Btw, to prevent overcomplication over inserting the autoincrementing value you can also skip the value itself, `INSERT INTO choice VALUES( '$shape','$color')"`. Anyway, are you still encountering problems?

Comment: I see, I did that in my registration which works fine. Unfortunately, it's still isn't working good. I tried putting it in different file this time. Something like this  `Warning: PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known` (line). then this too connection error : 
`:SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known`.

Comment: In the "Review Modal", I tried making it like this `<form role="form" id="ps_entry" name="ps_entry" method="post" action="ordersent.php">`  .  I'm afraid it won't read my "data" since the data that I'm retrieving is from "review modal" from the customization part (which were only displayed). sorry If I'm so eager about this. I've really appreciate your patience with me.

Comment: I think it'll work as the review modal is invoked with `<?php ?>`, unless you're using specific view technology that prevent the php gets parsed within the modal tags. And about the `no host exception`, means the host of the db itself, as you're using xampp then its localhost, now that it's throwing you errors, then the problems are around it, make sure the configuration for the db is correct. But if it shows blank within the review modal tags then the php part doesn't get rendered.